# How is heat and temperature related? How will a thermometer react in the following conditions?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature

Consider the cooking stove and LPG fuel for example, all my questions will be related to it.

Assume I have a frying pan made of steel which is kept on the the stove with the knob set to moderate.
Questions :

1. Will the pan ever melt if I never took it off the stove with an unlimited supply of fuel? (How will a thermometer react int this case?)
2. If not, will the pan melt if I increase the burner's radius so that more flame can hit the pan? (How will a thermometer react int this case?)
3. If not, will the pan melt if I set the gas knob to max, or will it only take less time for the pan to melt by increasing the knob (if melting is possible)? (How will a thermometer react int this case?)

What will the factor be to melt the steel pan?

Comment: If you are able to somehow cancel all the heat going out from  the steel pan (radiation,convection,conduction) surely it is going to melt regardless of sim or max flame . only the time taken will differ for the two flames.

Answer (score 1):

A flame requires an oxidizer. For the cooking stove, that means it would have to be in the air. The melting point for steel is around 1300-1500C (depending on grade and quality). Most LPG fuels don't reach a burn temperature above 2000C (note that's an ideal case, but you won't reach that with a commercially available cooking stove). You have the knob set to moderate, so the flame probably won't get anywhere near 2000C. Then, once you account for radiative cooling, conductive cooling with whatever the pan is resting on, and the increased convective cooling from all the air motion that such high temperatures would cause, it's safe to say that in standard conditions, this stove will never be able to melt the steel pan. It *may* soften the steel, but not melt it.

But you asked what happens to the thermometer when the steel pan melts. Okay, to melt the steel pan the flame needs to be hot enough. The fuel does allow for this, so let's say this is a custom designed stove that can get a 1900C flame. Then we should cover the pan with a reflective dome (or similar cover). Wide enough so as not to touch the pan and reflective to keep most of the radiation inside it. That would also keep the hot air around the pan, but we need to make sure not to smother the flame. There has to be a vent to allow oxygenated air into the burner. If we do this, it's possible to get everything hot enough to melt the steel pan.

What happens to the thermometer? That really depends on the thermometer. Is it a glass-alcohol or glass-mercury thermometer? Is it a digital thermometer? Is it rated for these high temperatures? Is it an IR thermometer? An IR thermometer will be fine. It will record the temperature of whatever it is pointed at. A digital thermometer could melt. But if it's rated for those temperatures, it will be fine. An analog thermometer (one with a bulb and liquid inside) is not a smart thing to use. If the casing doesn't melt, you could get boiling of the liquid and it could explode. But as usual, if the thermometer is rated for that temperature, it will be fine.

Comment: steel melting temperature is surely less than 1594 C. I think you mean 2500F ?

Comment: @Gowtham Yes, I did. Sorry, I was reading a huge table that flipped back and forth between F and C and my head saw F but read C

Comment: hey perks of having a material science student here :)

Comment: @Gowtham Yeah, I should have caught it too. Luckily I had you here for me :)

Comment: You could also add something for the thermometer case and conditions needed for the steel to actually melt .

Comment: Hey guys, I'm still puzzled. My intention of asking this question was to learn in which of these cases the reading of a thermometer will change. I have trouble understanding what alters the reading, the heat, or the temperature? Does increasing the knob increase the temperature, or does it only increases the burning rate? And thus how it will affect the pan and any ideal thermometer that can measure the fluctuations in variables.

Comment: @Sidsec9 so then what does that have to do with the pan melting?

Comment: I thought that would explain my doubt more clearly

Comment: @Sidsec9 Well, from these comments I'm now more uncertain what you're trying to ask. Are you trying to ask how an LPG stove works? or are you asking if a thermometer measures the rate of combustion? I don't get the question. A thermometer will measure the temperature. If the temperature changes, it will read the change.

Comment: @Jim I'll rephrase it, when we increase/decrease the knob on the stove or any burner, what happens exactly? Does increasing the knob increase the heat supply or the temperature or does it just supply constant heat at a faster rate (to the frying pan in my case)?
I don't understand the relation between heat and temperature. If I change the burner size, what will increase? The temperature or the heat?